# C# update parent object when new child is added

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

Not my scenario, but I have constructed this example to find out how to solve my problem.  Using Entity Framework I have the following models;

```
namespace ClassTesting.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Player
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Player()
        {
            this.Deposit_Transactions = new HashSet<Deposit_Transactions>();
        }

        public long id { get; set; }
        public string player_name { get; set; }
        public decimal player_balance { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Deposit_Transactions> Deposit_Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ClassTesting.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Deposit_Transactions
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime transaction_date { get; set; }
        public decimal transaction_amount { get; set; }
        public long fk_player_id { get; set; }

        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So a Player can have many Deposit_Transactions.

What I want to do is whenever a new Deposit_Transaction is posted, update the Player's player_balance attribute.  I can do that, but my solution is really clunky and involves fetching the player record and doing the update after the deposit has been made.  What I want to know is what is the "best practice" method for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `player_balance` is some aggregation of that player's `Deposit_Transactions`, I strongly recommend that you remove `player_balance` from the corresponding database table. Currently, your model is denormalized, storing the same conceptual information in multiple locations and thereby allowing it to get out of sync.

This is a larger problem, not confined to your EF model, increasing the likelihood of bugs throughout the whole system.

You can remove the column from the table and change `player_balance` into a readonly, computed property retaining its convenience.

```
public partial class Player
{
    public decimal player_balance => 
        Deposit_Transactions.Sum(transaction => transaction.transaction_amount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aluan.  Not being a programmer, I can't quite work out how to get the player_balance now.  I tried this;
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(var db = new ClassTestingEntities())
            {
                var player = (from p in db.Players where p.id == 1 select p);
                decimal pb = player.player_balance;
            }
        }`

but then it didn't like player.player_balance.  So I tried;

`Player player = (from p in db.Players where p.id == 1 select p);`

But it could not convert from Linq to the object.

Comment: Sorry, I just need a little more guidance.  Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, I was just missing the .First() in my second attempt.  Works fine now.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see your message. FYI: you can pass your predicate directly to `First` as in `var player1 = db.Players.First(player => player.Id == 1);`